# How to add resource files in in /src/main/resource after deploying mule application in mmc

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have just deployed for the first time a mule application in Mule management console(MMC),after deploying I want to add csv file in src/main/resourses/input folder. where can I find path and add csv file to that path.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the below image for details.

In other words,

Click on Servers tab --> Server --> Files tab --> apps --> Select your application --> classes --> Click on New File button --> Upload file.

[image]

But I suggest, keep your file in some other location and read it instead of keeping with in application folder structure.Problem is if you re-deploy the app from MMC, whatever files you have added manually from MMC will be deleted as MMC will take application from repository and deploy into server whenever you do re-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

> {MULE_HOME}/apps/{my app}/classes/{input folder}

Any folders under *src/main/resourses*  will reside under the *classes* folder found in your *app* folder, which is under the *apps* folder of the standalone Mule server.

Comment: should I create folder name with "input" and paste the csv file in the input folder .so that application will take file and process flow?

Comment: That will work as long as your file connector is pointing to that input folder.
If this is a file that is regularly added or updated, I would suggest like @RamakrishnaN suggested and place the file elsewhere, independent of the application. Your flow can directly refer to that location instead.
Of course, if you have a separate location, your application will need to have rights to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this path

/opt/mule-standalone-3.7.0/apps/{appname}/classes